# Git flow: why the tag is not placed on the master branch?

Tags: git, git-flow

I experiencing with [git-flow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) and I don't understand why during `git flow release finish v3.10beta2` the tag is not added to the version on the `master`.

```
$ git l --all
*   0b873f0 Merge branch 'release/v3.10beta2' into develop (HEAD -> develop)
|\
| | *   afd7ae2 Merge branch 'release/v3.10beta2' (master)
| | |\
| | |/
| |/|
| * | 1c3bf06 Bumped version [git flow release start v3.10beta2] (tag: v3.10beta2)
|/ /
* | 3277a37 Feature foo added [git flow feature finish foo]
|/
* 67c55af Initial commit
```

Is there any obvious reason for that?

Comment: Have you done any research? For example: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/432

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was the case initially (ie tagging on `master`), but that means the `develop` branch does not see said tag when doing a [`git describe --tags`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) (as stated in [issue 374](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/374))

Wrong tag:

[image: gitflow]
<sup>Image from the outdated [gitflow cheatsheet](http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)</sup>

If the `vX.X.X` tag is set on release instead of `master`, then `develop` can see the latest tag.

Comment: I see the logic here, but this causes a lot of ramifications (lots of merges)

Comment: @nowox those merges were always part of gitflow, but the tag needs to be correctly placed to be visible by the relevant branches.

Comment: @nowox Note: there are criticisms to that model, of course: http://barro.github.io/2016/02/a-succesful-git-branching-model-considered-harmful/, https://dotdev.co/a-git-workflow-for-client-facing-sign-off-28b7683bf01c#.4lvr5bu24